# Regex match when pattern matches, but a string is missing

Tags: regex

I have a series of firewall configs that I need to investigate. For example:

```
edit "username"
    set trusthost1 123.456.789.0 255.255.255.255
    set password ENC lkajsdf;lajksd
next
```

and

```
edit "username"
    set vdom "root" "somethinghere"
next
```

Please note that the configs are longer than these examples and that there can be many lines with arbitrary content between the "edit" and "next" lines.

I am trying to identify any user accounts without passwords (as in the second example). I have this expression, which matches the first config and not the second (as expected):

```
(edit \".*\"(\n|.)*set password(\n|.)*?next)
```

Now I am trying to negate it, so that the second config is caught. I though I could just add "?!" inside the parenthesis, but that is not working. In regex101.com, I just end up with a bunch of purple lines (looks like null groups).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post the link to your regex101

Comment: Also, add the tag of the language you are using JavaScript, PHP, Python, etc.

Comment: The link to the site ie: https://regex101.com/ and I just paste the expression into the top box, there is no link that is more specific. Also, the default language is PHP >=7.3 but I get the same result selecting any other option from the "Flavor" panel.

Comment: Is each config tested in turn, or are they all in one string?

Comment: Ok, go to the actual test you are using ATM and ctrl+s

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex in MULTILINE mode in PCRE:

```sh
^edit\h(?:.*\R(?!.*\hpassword\h))+?next$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WcVBtl/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start a line
- `edit\h`: Match `edit` followed by a whitespace
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
  - `\R`: Match a line break
  - `(?!.*\hpassword\h)`: Negative lookahead condition to fail the match if we have line with word `password` surrounded by spaces on both sides
- `)+?`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 1 or more times (lazy match)
- `next$`: Match a line with `next`

Comment: @StackExchangeGuy: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can match user configs with no password using this regex:

```
\h*edit ".*\n(?:\h*+(?!next|set password).*\n)*\h*next
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/PEk68c/2)

Comment: Note that using `\h+` requires at least a single leading space to be present, not sure if that is required.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Good point. Fixed.